# PHP : How to download dot csv file from my gmail Account?

Tags: php, gmail, download, incoming-mail

i have thousand of email in my gmail account.In the email i have a many files in each email but i need to download a file with csv extension and copy it to folder in my PC.
Any idea how would i do this in PHP ??

Comment: Connect via IMAP (or POP3, whatever), get all emails and then get the csv files... just a guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find [this](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap) useful, for the basics of connecting to gmail from PHP/IMAP.

And [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/extract-attachments-email-php-imap/) is more detailed info about getting attachments via IMAP.

You can easily filter the attachments by filename to get only .CSV files, using [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or even [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).